# Android Layout - Position issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to Android and I'm building small app in order to get the basics. I'm facing a dumb issue which, apparently, I can't seem to be able to fix.

I'm building a screen that looks like this on the designer[image]

However, when starting the emulator, the design looks like this:

[image]

Can you please advice me what I'm doing wrong? My xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.todorivanov.mytaskmanager.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:text="Buy"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="27dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:text="Add task"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="27dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOld"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Unfinished"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="27dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="107dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="18dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageAdd"
    android:layout_width="314dp"
    android:layout_height="358dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.421"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.497"
    app:srcCompat="@android:color/background_light" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgBtnClose"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="312dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="106dp" />
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use relative or Linear Layout to achieve what you are looking for. Following is the code for RelativeLayout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context="com.example.todorivanov.mytaskmanager.MainActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation = "horizontal"
    android:id = "@+id/buttons">
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:text="Buy"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="27dp" />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:text="Add task"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="27dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOld"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Unfinished"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="27dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
</LinearLayout>
    <CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_below = "@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="107dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="18dp" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageAdd"
    android:layout_width="314dp"
    android:layout_height="358dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.421"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.497"
    app:srcCompat="@android:color/background_light" />

    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgBtnClose"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="312dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="106dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

close any other tags ..

now you'll get the calenderView under the buttons just like the editor preview but you may need to adjust the padding/margin according to your requirements.

Hope this helps..

Comment: The LinearLayout isn't needed. It only introduces another level of nesting, therefore, affecting the overall performances.

Comment: yes but you'll have to modify codes for all the buttons or any other view at the top to make it work. so i believe its clean to add properties to only one view and put all other views in that one view.

Comment: So, you prefer to sacrifice performances in the name of what you find cleaner?!

Comment: and please tell me about the performance issues that my arise because of nesting because I'm doing this a lot in my development, so i can avoid it.

Comment: For beginner, it does need to use basic things. Use constrain-layout is not a good idea.

Comment: A beginner should learn things the best way, not the worst. [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html) is a little discussion on the topic. And [here](http://blog.trifork.com/2015/02/23/basic-android-ui-performance/). And [here](http://www.rapidvaluesolutions.com/tech_blog/best-practices-for-android-user-interface/). Anyhow, nowadays we should take advantage of the new ConstraintLayout, which is the improved version of the RelativeLayout.

Comment: CinstraintLayout can be used here. Reason is constrains are set incorrectly, designer is not always accurate

Answer (score 1):

**use Relative layout and code like this**

Edited with suggestion of **performance** as said by Rotwang

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Buy"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="27dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:text="Add task"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="27dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOld"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Unfinished"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="27dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnOld"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="107dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="18dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageAdd"
        android:layout_width="314dp"
        android:layout_height="358dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.421"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.497"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/background_light" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtnClose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="312dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="106dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**output**[image]

Comment: The LinearLayout isn't needed. It only introduces another level of nesting, therefore, affecting the overall performances.